# Anybody interested in doing a Catechism?

Tags: discussion

Might be kind of cool if we kept up a C.SE Ecumenical Cateschisim (Providence has provided my misspelling with a delightful pun).  I know it's not strictly necessary with tagging and all that, but seriously, why not?  We could just make one CW(ish) meta post, structure it to cover all the bases (for example)

- Prayer
- Faith
- Salvation
- Moral Life (that would be where most those [biblical-basis](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biblical-basis) for what I've been doing that past 50 years questions go)
- <strike>Bible Trivia</strike>
- etc..

might be kind of fun, might be a waste of time, but at least it'd be something to do.

---

We've got Tag wiki's but, this would be for meta-tag wikis with human-understandable hierarchies and categorization.

Answer (score 2):

### Bible Trivia

When St. Peter meets you at the [pearly gates](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/266/68), he won't ask you a question about Scripture to find out if you are worthy of admittance.  Fun fact: while Peter had [unique](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/8633/914) [attributes](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/6002/914) that would make him a perfect gatekeeper, the Bible doesn't actually say that he (or anyone else) will test people at the entrance of heaven.

If you are still interested in impractical knowledge about the New Testament and the Tanakh, please see [our sister site](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/).

---

I love the idea of a Cateschisim, but I'm not sure I know how it would work in practice.  Does the above section seem like a good start?  Or are you thinking something more like what [tag wikis](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/) are supposed to be, but in a meta-post?

Comment: I'm thinking something like the [Meta.SO FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)  The links could be either to other meta questions all starting with "What C.SE questions are about X" or the links could be to answers within that same question. I think, as long as we keep it Meta and keep it questions, the SE Overlords won't find it a distasteful absute of the system.