# What is the guideline for near-duplicates that are duplicate by pattern, but not in specifics?

Tags: discussion

Take the following pattern/formula, which we see repeated all over the site:

> Is there any teaching about whether anyone with (*insert limitation
>   that would prevent them from hearing/understanding the Gospel here*)
>   can get to heaven?

Examples:

- [What does the Bible say about people with mental illness?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4521/what-does-the-bible-say-about-people-with-mental-illness)
- [Where do children go when they die if they are born into sin?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12617/biblically-is-there-such-a-thing-as-innocent-by-reason-of-mental-defect)
- [Biblically, is there such a thing as innocent by reason of mental defect?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12617/biblically-is-there-such-a-thing-as-innocent-by-reason-of-mental-defect)
- [What does the Roman Catholic church teach about those who die having never heard of Christ?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/what-does-the-roman-catholic-church-teach-about-those-who-die-having-never-heard)
- [What happens to people who have never heard about Jesus?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/what-happens-to-people-who-have-never-heard-about-jesus)
- [What of all those who just don't know](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7323/what-of-all-those-who-just-dont-know)
- [When are children held accountable for their sins?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/319/when-are-children-held-accountable-for-ther-sins)
- [Is an intellectual comprehension of the gospel by the earthly mind required for salvation?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/18913/is-an-intellectual-comprehension-of-the-gospel-by-the-earthly-mind-required-for)

In my mind, these are all pretty much the same question (The formula question posited at the beginning of this post), with the variables changed...  Perhaps it could be broken down into two questions:

> - What about those who have never heard because ___________?
> - What about those that do not have the capacity to understand because _________?

The difference between each is miniscule, and the answer pretty much remains the same no matter what you plug into the blank.  Are these considered to be duplicates, or do we need to have an exact duplicate for it to count?

On the one hand, I can see why these might be hard to search if the specific instance changes, but that's also part of the point.  Closing as a duplicate isn't the kiss of death for a question.  Doing so automatically links to the previous question, so that if a user searches for either, they will still end up at the original answer.

Comment: I wish the Stacks Exchange has the ability to make related questions link up by a web.

Comment: Note I'm not out to push my way of viewing this, I'm honestly asking if I'm looking at it wrong.

Comment: I guess the litmus test for me is the answers. If the answer to A and B is the same then they are effectively duplicates.

Comment: @waxeagle Can I talk you into turning that into an answer?

Comment: @DavidStratton let me sleep on it and I'll give it a stab in the morning. Ping me in chat if you don't see something by lunchtimeish

Comment: @waxeagle I still don't see that answer :)

Comment: Since I cannot understand, can you better explain the question in order to make it more clear, please?

Comment: I agree in principle, but I disagree that these examples are all the same question.  For questions of this type, we could have two biblical basis questions (one against and one for), as well as multiple questions scoped to particular traditions: Roman Catholic, various branches of Protestantism, etc.

Answer (score 6):

I will fulfill David's request (made in an answer comment) for more responses to this old question...

Questions should be considered duplicate when the answers will inevitably be the same, even if the question is nominally different.  If none of the existing questions are sufficiently broadly worded, creating a new question and closing the older ones as duplicates is a possibility.  That is precisely what we did for the [Messianic Secret](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/42897/) question, after a [meta discussion](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4671/messianic-secret-questions).

Answer (score 0):

We could do what I [suggested here](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1304/anybody-interested-in-doing-a-catechism) the humanity of meta.cse can solve some of the deficiencies of the AI and pattern matching in the main site.

How did you come up with those examples anyway?

Comment: I searched for variations of "mental capacity", "ability to understand" and "never heard".