# Intent of Christianity.SE and the new SO Documentation feature

Tags: discussion, scope

I believe that the intent of this SE is to document specific questions and answers regarding a specific denomination or belief/practice. We propose not answering truth question or giving advise.

With that said, is https://stackoverflow.com/documentation format a better format for this SE?  If documentation comes to SE's, how can we leverage this format?

Answer (score 6):

The SO Documentation format is highly tuned for the programming world. It's great for what it sets out to do (at least I think it will be), and some parts of it would be applicable to us — but using just parts of it as a way to organize documentation would set us on a course to walk all over Wikipedia and other sites. The difference between theology and programming is that Wikipedia only covers what things are, not *how to use them with code samples* and that turns out to be very useful in programming. There was a gap between Q&A and other extant documentation. That's what the void that SO Documentation aims to fill. I'm not sure there is such a gap for us, and if there is I'm not sure we should be filling it. The analog for us would not so much be documenting the beliefs of Christianity but giving examples of how to put those beliefs into practice.

In other words: becoming a full on self-help directory.

No thanks.

Lets wait (not that we have a choice, SE isn't actually offering the features to other sites yet and may never do so) and see how it plays out before we wring our hands to much over the possibilities.

Comment: Agreed.  With that said, we should at least keep it in the back of our mind and consider how we could leverage this feature should it become available.  Maybe some have more time than others to consider such things.  I am also not saying we should hold our breath for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what "SO Documentation" is, but it looks like what we do could be that. However, it's dry to read and doesn't seem to encourage participation. Also, it just seems like real answers were pulled out of the main site and put there. I can see the allure for code, allowing you to study a specific language; I think that's an attractive prospect for Christianity SE, but I wonder how this improves over tags on the main site. We can already search and filter by tags. Also, often, more than one answer on this site is worth reading and adds something unique to the question.

Short answer: maybe, and I'm willing to try it.

Comment: Eh, we tried to use the blog feature but that didn't work out.

Comment: @thefreemason I think that was a participation thing. I want to blog, but doing it well is time intensive.

Comment: Maybe what I'm envisioning is a blog.  IDK.  I guess an example of what I was thinking is a topic like, "Does the bread and wine become the body and blood or just a symbol" which examples could be made by different denominations as "examples"

Answer (score 0):

It would be fun, I suggested a couple of years ago that we [start a catechism](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1304/anybody-interested-in-doing-a-catechism) on meta, but that didn't meet with much approbation.

The problem would be sticking to a set of rules.  A.) Because the rules would be confusing and B.) Because you would have to enforce the confusing rules.